# Server Sent Event не работает в Mozila

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sse

Я открываю sse соединение на стороне клиента

```
       let sseSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:7777/connect');

        sseSource.addEventListener('open', (e) => {

            console.log("Событие: open");
            // socket = new Class['class']
        })
        sseSource.addEventListener('error', (e) => {

            console.log("Событие: error", sseSource);
            if (this.readyState === sseSource.CONNECTING) {
                console.log(`Переподключение (readyState=${this.readyState})...`);
            } else {
                console.log("Произошла ошибка.");
            }
        });
        sseSource.addEventListener('ping', (e) => {

            console.log(e)
        });
```

На стороне сервера тоже всё стандартно.
express server.

```
app.options('/connect', cors(corsOptions))
app.get('/connect',  async (req, res) => {
    console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream; charset=utf-8',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
        // 'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    });
    res.write('\n');
    res.write("event: " + 'ping' + "\n" + "data: " + JSON.stringify({ version: `server side events true`, date:Date.now()}) + "\n\n");
});
```

В хроме переподключение и connect работает.

А в мозила первый раз подключение проходит успешно.

```
Событие: open localhost:7777:26:21
ping
​
bubbles: false
​
cancelBubble: false
​
cancelable: false
​
composed: false
​
currentTarget: null
​
data: "{\"version\":\"server side events true\",\"date\":1574466971308}"
​
defaultPrevented: false
​
eventPhase: 0
​
explicitOriginalTarget: EventSource { url: "http://localhost:7777/connect", withCredentials: false, readyState: 1, … }
​
isTrusted: true
​
lastEventId: ""
​
origin: "http://localhost:7777"
​
originalTarget: EventSource { url: "http://localhost:7777/connect", withCredentials: false, readyState: 1, … }
​
ports: Array []
​
returnValue: true
​
source: null
​
srcElement: EventSource { url: "http://localhost:7777/connect", withCredentials: false, readyState: 1, … }
​
target: EventSource { url: "http://localhost:7777/connect", withCredentials: false, readyState: 1, … }
​
timeStamp: 56
​
type: "ping"
​
<get isTrusted()>: function isTrusted()
​
<prototype>: MessageEvent
```

Но если я перезагружаю страницу, появляется следующая ошибка.

```
The connection to http://localhost:7777/connect was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

И когда соединение обрывается со стороны сервера переподключение не происходит.

```
Событие: open localhost:7777:26:21
ping { target: EventSource, isTrusted: true, data: "{\"version\":\"server side events true\",\"date\":1574467108519}", origin: "http://localhost:7777", lastEventId: "", ports: Restricted, srcElement: EventSource, currentTarget: EventSource, eventPhase: 2, bubbles: false, … }
localhost:7777:40:21
Событие: error 
EventSource { url: "http://localhost:7777/connect", withCredentials: false, readyState: 2, onopen: null, onmessage: null, onerror: null }
localhost:7777:31:21
Произошла ошибка. localhost:7777:35:25
```

В чём может быть причина ? В хроме этот код работает и происходит переподключение.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса странный. SSR не может работать или не работать в браузере. Он же server side

Comment: Оууу..исправил. Я иммел ввиду server side event